# Writing multiple csv's from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Let's say that I have a function which creates a pd.DataFrame according to some variable 'name':

```
 def function(name):
 ...
 ...
 ...
 return(DataFrame(name)) #parenthesis 
                         #here only to show that the DataFrame will be
                         #different when a different name is given as input.
```

My question is: how can I write a function to write a .csv (with a unique name) for each possible value for 'name'?

For example, 'name' could belong to the list:

```
example=['Ben','Steve','Mary']
```

which would output 3 different .csv's: Ben.csv, Steve.csv, Mary.csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I'm not completely sure about your question: do you want to write a different CSV with the same data in the dataframe (whatever it comes from your function), or to get the dataframe, extract the data associated by the name (ie in a col) and then write it to an specific output CSV file?

If you just want to take the dataframe and write it to different CSV files, it's not difficult at all:

```
for name in ['Ben', 'Steve', 'Mary']:
  pd.to_csv('.'.join([name, 'csv']), delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

If you would like to extract the column from the Dataframe given the name (from memory, I could be wrong):

```
for name in ['Ben', 'Steve', 'Mary']:
   user_data = df[[name]]   # This will create a copy dataframe.
   user_data.to_csv('.'.join([name,'csv']), delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: No need to be sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough. The function creates a unique mxn DataFrame, depending on what name is used (ie: imagine the function is sub-setting some larger dataset according to the name used). I want to take each of the DataFrames produced (by each name) and export each one as a seperate .csv- I think your second example is more close to what I needed in that respect.

Comment: Your second solution works great :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Ben','Steve','Mary','Ben','Steve','Mary'], 'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

def write_custom_csv(name):
    filtered = df[df['name'] == name]
    filtered.to_csv(name + '.csv')
```

You just pass whatever name as `name` in the function, and the function will filter the global `pandas.DataFrame` called `df` based on the passed name. Then that "filtered" DataFrame is written to file.

Comment: Ah! I forgot about the filtering with df['name'] == name, good point!